# NAPTR DNS in Gandi registrar

Tags: domain-name-system

as it's said on https://community.hetzner.com/tutorials/install-turn-stun-server-on-debian-ubuntu-with-coturn i have to add this in my Gandi DNS :

```
@ IN NAPTR 10 0 "s" "RELAY:turn.udp" "" _turn._udp.example.com.
```

But every time i try to add this, i have an syntax error, so what's wrong in this line ? I have successfully added the others lines needed but not this one.

Cdlt

Answer (score 1):

Does "Gandi DNS" mean "[Gandi's Live DNS](https://docs.gandi.net/en/domain_names/faq/dns_records.html#where-can-i-edit-my-dns-resource-records)"? While it does have support for [NAPTR records](https://docs.gandi.net/en/domain_names/faq/record_types/naptr_record.html), the web interface seems to support the *obsolete* specification from September 2000 in [RFC 2915](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2915), and even that only partially. You may contact their support with your issue.

Also, the [LiveDNS API](https://api.gandi.net/docs/livedns/) is a lot more flexible than the "DNS Records" tab. Although I didn't test it, you might be able to add your [RFC 5928](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5928) (*Traversal Using Relays around NAT (TURN) Resolution Mechanism*) records using the API.